# TCP only doesn't works with public IP

Tags: c, winapi, tcp, ip

I've written two functions, which should start a TCP-Server/Client. If I call them with the IP "127.0.0.1" (just for testing), then everything works fine. But if I call them with the public IP of my computer, I get a connection timeout. Has anybody an idea what could be the problem?

Here the Code:

Server:

```
bool fSTARTED = false;
struct timeval tv;

TCP_StartServer (const int iPort, SOCKET *iSOCKET)
{
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET iSOCKETListen;
SOCKADDR_IN tAdr;

if(!fSTARTED)
{
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa))
    {
        *iSOCKET = -1;
        return;
    }
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    fSTARTED = true;
}

iSOCKETListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

memset(&tAdr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
tAdr.sin_family = AF_INET;
tAdr.sin_port = htons(iPort);
tAdr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
if(bind(iSOCKETListen, (SOCKADDR*) & tAdr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    *iSOCKET = 0 - WSAGetLastError();
    return;
}

if(listen(iSOCKETListen, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    *iSOCKET =  0 - WSAGetLastError();
    return;
}

*iSOCKET = accept(iSOCKETListen, NULL, NULL);
if(*iSOCKET == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    *iSOCKET = 0 - WSAGetLastError();
    return;
}

return;
}
```

Client:

```
TCP_StartClient (char *sIP, const int iPort, SOCKET *iSOCKET)
{
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKADDR_IN tAdr;

if(!fSTARTED)
{
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa))
    {
        *iSOCKET = -2;
        return;
    }
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    fSTARTED = true;

}

*iSOCKET = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(*iSOCKET == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    *iSOCKET = 0 - WSAGetLastError();
    return;
}

memset(&tAdr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
tAdr.sin_family = AF_INET;
tAdr.sin_port = htons(iPort);
tAdr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(sIP);

if(connect(*iSOCKET, (SOCKADDR*) &tAdr, sizeof(SOCKADDR)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    *iSOCKET =  0 - WSAGetLastError();
    return;
}

return;
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `sIP` arg in `StartClient` in case of timeout?

Comment: Have you opened the corresponding port?

Comment: depending on the OS (Windows 2008, Windows 7 etc.) you could have a firewall configured which prevents this...

Comment: @Yahia I guess it's Windows, because of `WSADATA`.

Comment: @VictorSorokin I agree, but that doesn't tell us the Windows version and not all Windows version come with a built-in firewall...

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. And in sIP I put my current public IP like "212.60.44.90".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how a typical home computer network looks (simplified diagram and explanation):

```
        \     Internet     /
         \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
                  |
                  | 212.60.44.90 (public IP address)
           +-------------+
           | DSL router  |
           +-------------+
                  | 10.0.0.1 (private network router)
                  |
                  | 10.0.0.2 (private network address)
           +-------------+
           |Your computer|
           +-------------+
```

In this case the router is doing [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) from your local 10.0.0.x addresses to your public 212.60.44.90 address. Your computer is unaware of the public IP address that it ends up using, because that information is only in the DSL router. The point of NAT is that there may also be other computers on your local 10.0.0.x network, and they *share* the same public IP address (because there is only one).

Your router probably also acts as a firewall, preventing random incoming connections from the Internet from reaching your local computers. Normally the router will block *all* such incoming connections.

Given the above, you should be able to see why you cannot connect to your public 212.60.44.90 address from *within* your own network. Your computer sends the request to the router, which either ignores or blocks your request from a firewall perspective.

Depending on your router, you *may* be able to configure it to forward incoming requests to your public IP address to a specific computer on your 10.0.0.x network. You would have to set up this manually, and instructions about how to do that are beyond the scope of this answer.

Also, you may notice that you should be able to connect to your local computer on your local network address (10.0.0.2 in the diagram). However, that's not much more interesting than connecting to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: +1 also, most NAT routers will not forward requests when coming from the inside. I for instance can't connect to my server via the public IP when on the inside, I have to use the private IP. Makes it awfully hard to quickly test if I have set it up properly, always have to test from another connection.

Comment: Thank you for this really detailed answer. I think I understand it now. So I would need to try it with a Computer outside of my Network...

Answer (score 0):

This might not even be a problem with your code. Some computers (like mine) can't see itself when trying to access from the external IP. Try setting a loopback adapter for your external IP, also, check your NAT rules.

Comment: Ok, that could be. I'll try it with loopback adapter. I hope it works with it.

Comment: I tried to install the loopback adapter, but it doesn't work. It couldn't install the drivers. But I tested it now with another computer and it also didn't work. So it must be something else.